# Python unwanted empty lines after string strip

Tags: python, csv, syntax

I have a csv

```
"AA","AB","AC"
"BA","BB","BC"
"CA","CB","CC"
```

after removing a string say " the csv format changes to

```
AA,AB,AC

BA,BB,BC

CA,CB,CB
```

What should I do to avoid the unwanted lines ?

```
 import fileinput
 for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.csv",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace('"','')
    print (line)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're printing it, looks like Python 3, and looks like your file content already includes the necessary newlines. Therefore, you need to tell the `print()` function not to add its own newlines:

```
print(line, end='')
```

Comment: You want `end`, not `sep`.

Comment: Oops. I use `sep` a lot more often than `end`.

Answer (score 2):

When read each line includes the terminating new line character. Furthermore `print()` will also add a new line of it's own, so you end up with two new lines.

But you are not using `strip()` as suggested by your question's title.

To get around that you can use `rstrip()` to remove any whitespace at the end of each line:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.csv",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace('"','').rstrip()
    print (line)
```

That will get rid of the extra new line characters, but note that it will also remove other whitespace at the end of the line.

An alternative is to prevent `print()` adding its own new line:

Python 2:

```
print(line),    # comma prevents new line
```

Python 3:

```
print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Just curious: why the parens in the Python 2 version?

Comment: @ron.rothman: only because the OP had them in the question and it was not clear to me whether OP is using Python 2 or Python 3. They don't hurt in Python 2, so I left them there.

Comment: Technically, adding parentheses in Python 2 can turn something like `print 1,2,3` -> `1 2 3` into `print(1,2,3)` -> `(1, 2, 3)`. However, that's not a concern here because this question deals with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? You should use `csv` module , it would handle both the `,` as well as the quotes for you. Example -

```
import csv
with fileinput.FileInput('test.csv',inplace=1) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print (','.join(row))
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import csv
>>> with fileinput.FileInput('test.csv',inplace=1) as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(','.join(row))
...
AA,AB,AC
BA,BB,BC
CA,CB,CC
```

Comment: I think that OP wants to update the file in place, hence use of `fileinput`. That might not be a valid assumption however :)

Comment: csv module would work with fileinput as well. Update the code and example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing extra lines because the lines read from the file end with '\n' and the print(line) statement appends an extra newline.

You can use rstrip() to strip out the trailing newline:

```
 import fileinput
 for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.csv",inplace=1):
    line = line.rstrip().replace('"','')
    print (line)
```